# Hack to implement something like ARB_texture_float when it isn't supported?

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures

I'm doing some glsl processing on an integrated Intel GM965 graphics processor. For this, I need access to the full range floating point representation of a texture, rather than it be restricted to 0.0->1.0, as the usual internal formats dictate.

Now, under linux, the Mesa driver happily provides the ARB_texture_float extension, which I've been using fine. Under windows, the driver does not support this extension. Short of me buying a new laptop, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Update the driver. If not possible, tough luck. Intel GPUs are exceptionally bad at OpenGL. You might have better luck with DirectX on Windows.

Comment: *This extension is written against the OpenGL 2.0 Specification but will work with the OpenGL 1.5 Specification.* I also think it's time for a driver update, and Intel suck at anything related to GPUs =/

Comment: Yeah, I feared as much. An algorithm rewrite is the next option I think.

Comment: Maybe you could do something like this, to pack a floating point value into an RGBA? http://aras-p.info/blog/2008/06/20/encoding-floats-to-rgba-again/

Comment: @Tim I think that merits a solution!